# Bivariate fixed points

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Let $f(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, be a strictly decreasing, convex and continuous function in $x$ with $f(x)>0, \forall x>0$, with $\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\textrm{Lim}} f(x)=0$.

Let $g(y,x):\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with $g(y,x)>0, \forall x,y>0$, be a continuous and strictly decreasing function in $x$, with $\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\textrm{Lim }} g(y,x)=0$ and single-peaked function in $y$, with  $\underset{y\rightarrow\infty}{\textrm{Lim }} g(y,x)=0$.

Under which conditions (on $f$ and $g$) can I prove the existence of a point $x>0$ that satisfies
$$f(x)=g(f(x),x).$$
I suppose I should use Brouwers fixed point theorem, but am unsure about the approach.

Comment: It would be best to narrow down the criteria for $f$ and $g$ that interest you. At the moment it's too easy to provide a counterexample, e.g. when the range of $f$ does not intersect with the range of $g$.

Comment: @ChrisSanders: i've added details, that i know.